# How do I get back the PDE editors for site.xml and feature.xml?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wrote a simple Eclipse plugin, a Builder to do a bit of post-processing on Android library projects. It seemed to work fine, so I setup a department-visible update site, and deployed it. Once a few dozen people were using it, it turned out that I'm not handling project refresh quite right, and users *have to* clean and rebuild the project after a refresh. So, I set out to fix my bug.

And ran into a big problem.

I can open the plugin's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file just fine: I get the same PDE editor that I 'always' got. But, now, when I try to open the feature project's `feature.xml` or the site project's `site.xml`,

1. Eclipse pops up a `Unsupported Content Type` dialog.
2. If I click on the `Content Types Preference Page` link, and open  `Text / XML`, I see that `Feature Manifest File` is associated with `feature.xml (locked)` and `Update Site Manifest File` is associated with `site.xml (locked)`, as expected.
3. When I click on the `Unsupported Content Type` dialog's `OK` button, I get an Android `Failed to create the part's controls` error, and the `Details` button shows a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Android XML Editor Error`.

I tried closing and restarting Eclipse; I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Plug-in Development Environment. No help. Neither Google nor Stack Overflow showed any hint of anyone with a similar problem.

WTF? And, more importantly, **what do I do now?**

Comment: can you post some screenshots, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're running the newest Eclipse, Kepler SR1, and right-click on the file and pick the right editor in the Open With context menu. If that works, you might have to manually a File Association for feature.xml to the correct editor.

Comment: Thanks! "Open With" worked, even though I'm using (I think) Juno, not Kepler. (The ADT splash screen on this build hides the Eclipse version.)